# Labelling subject (S) and Verb (V) in learning English Grammar using LaTeX

Tags: latex

Can anyone help this.
How can I label english grammar symbols in a sentence in LaTeX?
For example.

1. Japan is country. label on top of the word **Japan** is noun, **IS** as verb

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256373/how-do-i-get-text-above-and-below-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions I found "cheat" using math-mode syntaxes despite their application to text mode. So here is my "cheating" sketch. I defined two `newcommand`s to use as many times as you need:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\isnoun}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{N}}{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isverb}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{V}}{\text{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\end{document}
```

Remember `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the header. The output looks like:

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

---

To add color(s) to the label or text you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{48, 122, 219}
\newcommand{\isnoun}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{{\color{color1}\mathbf{N}}}{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isverb}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{V}}{{\color{color2}\text{#1}}}}}

\begin{document}
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\end{document}
```

[image: same with colors]

Comment: MattAllegro,Thank you very much. so that means I can just add another command for new part of speech?.  This exact something was looking for. how can I add color to the text?. Thank you again

Comment: MattAllegro, Man thank you a lot.Let me play on it. solved problem

Comment: MattAllegro, how can I define another command for these: 1. Comma, plus sign and period in the same format as above?

Comment: @user3056542 if comma, plus and period are meant to be parts of the body of text, exactly as above, then \commandname{+} ... :)